# Trying to display 3 random selected cities alphabetically

Tags: java

Want to enter 3 cities in any order and want java to display them alphabetically. Thought about using the swap option but thought the enclosed code would work with an "if" "else" statement. Any ideas...Thanks

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class OrderTwoCities {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Prompt the user to enter two cities
    System.out.print("Enter the first city: ");
    String city1 = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter the second city: ");
    String city2 = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter the third city: ");
    String city3 = input.nextLine();

    if (city1.compareTo(city2) < 0 && city2.compareTo(city3) < 0)
        System.out.println("The cities in alphabetical order are " +
        city1 + " " + city2 + " " + city3);
    else
        System.out.println("The cities in alphabetical order are " +
        city3 + " " + city2 + " " + city1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to consider more cases, with just 2 you won't cover all possible orderings. Hint: there are 6 possibilities, not just 2. For the general case with an arbitrary number of elements, consider adding the cities to an `ArrayList` and sort it using `Collections.sort()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use Arrays.sort(arr) method to sort arr elements
Example:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String [] arr = new String[3];
// Prompt the user to enter two cities
System.out.print("Enter the first city: ");
arr[0] = input.nextLine();
System.out.print("Enter the second city: ");
arr[1] = input.nextLine();
System.out.print("Enter the third city: ");
arr[2] = input.nextLine();
Arrays.sort(arr);
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class OrderTwoCities {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

// Prompt the user to enter two cities
   System.out.print("Enter the first city: ");
   String city1 = input.nextLine();
   System.out.print("Enter the second city: ");
   String city2 = input.nextLine();
   System.out.print("Enter the third city: ");
   String city3 = input.nextLine();

 ArrayList<String> cities = new ArrayList<String>();
  cities.add(city1);
  cities.add(city2);
  cities.add(city3);
  Collections.sort(cities); // Sorting the cities in alphabetical order
  System.out.println("The cities in alphabetical order are : ");
  for (String city : cities) {
       System.out.println(city);
      }

    } 
}
```

Comment: @GaryStevenson : Please accept it as an answer clicking on the 'tick' beside and give it an up-vote. It would be helpful for others, too. Regards :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a list of the strings, sort it, then iterate through its contents like so:

```
System.out.println("Enter the names of 3 cities : ");
List<String> cities =new ArrayList<>();
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int x=0; x<3; x++){
    cities.add(s.nextLine());
}
 Collections.sort(cities);
 System.out.println("Cities in alphabetical order: ");
 for(String city:cities)
     System.out.print(city+" ");;
     System.out.println();
  } 
}
```